# Added todo-object in array(state) is not reversed immidiately

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm creating Todo CRUD app with React-redux on frontend. When I'm adding a new todo-object to the list of todos(array in state) I want new todo to be rendered at the very top, not the last. I just connect component to redux state(todo list) and reverse it. It works, though not immidiately but after some time. I suppose the problem is in lifecycle. Index component is connected to redux state. render lifecycle creates markup, maps over state array and only then Componentdidmount triggers thus updating the state, then rerender occurs and so the view. This it's not happening immidiately, but after some miliseconds. But I'm not sure and very confused, because I tried another lifecycle methods to no result...

List of todos component

```
Index.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { todoList } from '../actions/todoActions';
import TableRow from './TableRow';

class Index extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.todoList();
    };

    tabRow() {
        return this.props.allTodos.map(user => {
            return <TableRow obj={user} key={user._id} />
        });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h3 align="center">Todo List</h3>
          <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Surname</th>
                <th>Task</th>
                <th colSpan="2">Action</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              { this.tabRow() }
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      )
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    allTodos: state.todo.todos.reverse()
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { todoList }
)(Index);
```

Create todo

```
import React from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { registerTodo } from '../actions/todoActions';

class Create extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.userChangeHandler = this.userChangeHandler.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            name: '',
            surname: '',
            task: ''
        };
    }

    userChangeHandler(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value
        });
    };

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const newUserTodo = {
            name: this.state.name,
            surname: this.state.surname,
            task: this.state.task
        };
        this.props.registerTodo(newUserTodo, this.props.history);
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <div style={{marginTop: 10}}>
                <h3>Add New Task</h3>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Add Name: </label>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            name="name" 
                            className="form-control"
                            onChange={this.userChangeHandler}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Add Surname: </label>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            name="surname" 
                            className="form-control"
                            onChange={this.userChangeHandler}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label>Add Todo Task: </label>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            name="task" 
                            className="form-control"
                            onChange={this.userChangeHandler}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create Todo" className="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
};


export default connect(
  null,
  { registerTodo }
)(withRouter(Create));
```

Todo item

```
TableRow

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { deleteTodo } from '../actions/todoActions';

class TableRow extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
        <tr>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj.name}
          </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj.surname}
          </td>
          <td>
            {this.props.obj.task}
          </td>
          <td>
            <Link to={'/edit/'+this.props.obj._id} className="btn btn-primary">Edit</Link>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button onClick={this.props.deleteTodo.bind(this, this.props.obj._id)} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
    );
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  allTodos: state.todo.todos
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { deleteTodo }
)(TableRow);
```

actions

```
export const registerTodo = (userTodo, history) => dispatch => {
    axios
        .post('/api/users/add', userTodo)
        .then(res => {
            dispatch(setTodo(userTodo));
            history.push('/index');
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
};

export const setTodo = todo => {
    return {
        type: ADD_TODO,
        payload: todo
    };
};

export const todoList = () => dispatch => {
    axios
        .get('/api/users')
        .then(res => {
            dispatch(getTodos(res.data));
        });
};

export const getTodos = todos => {
    return {
        type: GET_TODOS,
        payload: todos
    }
};
```

reducers

```
const initialState = {
    todos: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: [...state.todos, action.payload]
            };
        case GET_TODOS:
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: [...action.payload]
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I honestly didn't understand the question properly. But from what I gathered, you want the new todo to be placed in the front of the rest.
That can be done by switching the positions in your ADD_TODO reducer.

```
case ADD_TODO:
    return {
        ...state,
        todos: [action.payload, ...state.todos]
    };
```

EDIT:
The api call to get the todos may not do the same, and just appends it to the end. In that case, if you can, you should handle it in there. (OR) you should do that on your own right after you get the data from the api. And since this is done in the componentDidMount(), there will be a delay as it is called after the first render. Adding a spinner is a way around that.

Comment: Yes. I want the new todo to be placed in the front of the rest, but when I'm adding new todo it does not happen immidiately. At first the view shows that new todo is in the end of the list, but right after miliseconds it places new todo at the very top of this list. I'm wondering what is the reason of this slight delay and how to solve it

Comment: I don't understand how it is even placing the new todo at the very top, I'm guessing it's being handled in the api call?
Anyway, try the above solution, it should do the trick.

Comment: in mapStateToProps in Index component by reverse() method

Comment: Why are you reversing the entire array? Can you remove the reverse() and try the above solution?

Comment: Can you add the code to codesandbox or somewhere and post the link here? It would make it easier to check.

Comment: I understood what you issue is, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Did just like you said.
1) Reversed array in api call
2)`todos: [action.payload, ...state.todos]`
And everything works fine, without any delay=) Thanks

Comment: Cool. Glad to be of help.